# How can I make a function which returns some View and accepts a closure in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want build a function for View which accepts a closure like `onChange` or `onPreferenceChange` here is my code, with this code I can read `value` or the change of `value`, but I cannot send it back to my **ContentView**, because I want use `print(newValue)` in **ContentView**. How can I do this? thanks for your help and time.

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var stringOfText: String = "Hello, world!"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(stringOfText)
            .perform(value: stringOfText) // <<: Here: I want get back data as: { newValue in print(newValue) }

        Button("update") { stringOfText += " updated!" }.padding()
        
        
    }
}
```

---

```
extension View {
    
    func perform(value: String) -> some View {
        
        return self
            .preference(key: CustomPreferenceKey.self, value: value)
            .onPreferenceChange(CustomPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in

                print(newValue)
                
                // I want send back newValue to ContentView that perform used!
                
            }

    }
    
}
```

---

```
struct CustomPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: String { get { return String() } }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout String, nextValue: () -> String) { value = nextValue() }
    
}
```

Comment: `onChange` doesn't "return a closure". Do you mean function that _accepts a closure_?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do. Can you provide an example of usage for this?

Comment: @Sweeper: Yes, sorry. I just typed wrong, but updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so we only need to add callback closure parameter in perform function. like this

```
func perform(value: String,callback : @escaping (_ value : String ) -> Void) -> some View
```

so now we have a callback closure in which we can send the value back.

```
  struct ContentView: View {
            @State private var stringOfText: String = "Hello, world!"
            var body: some View {
                Text(stringOfText)
                    .perform(value: stringOfText) {
                        newValue in
                        print(newValue)
                    }
                Button("update") { stringOfText += " updated!" }.padding()
            }
        }
     
   
   extension View {
        func perform(value: String,callback : @escaping (_ value : String ) -> Void) -> some View {
            return self
                .preference(key: CustomPreferenceKey.self, value: value)
                .onPreferenceChange(CustomPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in
                    callback(newValue)
                }
        }
    }
    
    struct CustomPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: String { get { return String() } } 
        static func reduce(value: inout String, nextValue: () -> String) { value = nextValue() }
        
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please add an explanation of what the code does

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @JoakimDanielson . I have added the explanation.